# HTTP Post message to Private Telegram Channel Does Not Work

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, channel

When I create a public channel and use

curl -i -X GET "https://api.telegram.org/bot[YourKey]/sendMessage?chat_id=[@YourChannelName]&text=[YourText]"

where YourChannelName is the end of t.me/XXXXX that is set for the public link, it works just fine. I use the response from this to get the chat_id number.

But when I switch it to private, and use the -100XXX... Chat ID number it does not work. This is the accepted solution for multiple old threads. Has something changed?

Even if I use the chat_id -100... number for YourChannelName in a public chat it does not work. It has only worked with the end of the public shareable link exactly. Is there a different way to use an HTTP POST or GET to send a message to a private channel?